# Converting redux client from REST to GraphQL Apollo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, graphql, react-apollo

I have this rest app that gets data like this, with thunk + promise middlewares for redux:

```
export const fetchVenues = () => ({
    type: 'FETCH_VENUES',
    payload: axios.get('http://localhost:3000/mock/venues'),
});
```

The data from this goes into the store and components use the fetched data from there.

Can I swap the rest request in "payload" with a graphql query or something?

What confuses me is that Redux says: "Data lives in the store and can only be changed by actions", but Apollo binds the data directly to the components.
I've already made a GraphQL API, works great in the graphiql devtool, but I'm a bit confused by the way it's handled in the client after reading [**this article**](https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/seamless-integration-for-graphql-and-react-6ffc0ad3fead#.sf0h83fuf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that internally, apollo uses redux. Basically it makes you collocate the query with the component and injects (connect) the related data + functions as props. It also manages the store for you, by updating the cache / store upon request completion.

You can see that ApolloProvider is a redux provider on steroids: https://github.com/apollostack/react-apollo/blob/01425b3df5f05e7f389b36f3385433c89a39977b/src/ApolloProvider.tsx

I hope this helps your understanding a little.